# StopPropagation com right click / clique direito

Tags: javascript, jquery

Com esse código consigo parar a propagação de um menu dropdown clicando ao clicar no documento. Funciona muito bem. Agora eu gostaria realizar a mesma coisa, mas com o clique direito.

A mágica ocorre graças ao `event.stopPropagation();`
dentro de `onclick` qual o equivalente disso para o right click? Será que é possível uma utilização dupla?

**Código funcional.**

`$(document).on('click','.body-jq-dropdown',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});`

**Exemplo**

O objetivo é, que quando o fundo vermelho for habilitado, seja possível remove-lo com um clique no documento.

```js
$(document).on('click','.add-red-bg',function(event){
  jQuery('body').addClass('body-red-habilitado');
});
$(document).on('click contextmenu','.body-red-habilitado', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    jQuery('body').removeClass('body-red-habilitado');
    console.clear();
    console.log(event.type);
});
```

```css
body {
  background:#eee;
}

.body-red-habilitado {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-red-bg">Habilitar Background RED</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O evento `contextmenu` significa que o botão direito foi clicado. Basta adiciona-lo na lista de eventos do método `.on()`.

Mas o problema também é que o `stopPropagation()` deve ser aplicado ao botão e não ao `document`.

**Veja:**

```js
$('.add-red-bg').on('click contextmenu',function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   $('body').addClass('body-red-habilitado');
});

$(document).on('click contextmenu', function(event){
    $('body').removeClass('body-red-habilitado');
    console.clear();
    console.log(event.type);
});
```

```css
body {
  background:#eee;
}

.body-red-habilitado {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-red-bg">Habilitar Background RED</button>
```

Comment: Funciona apenas com click padrão. Existe um botão que quando clicado adiciona no body a classe `.body-jq-dropdown`.

Comment: Não funcionou com o clique direito?

Comment: Não, sei que aqui está funcionando... no geral não, apenas o esquerdo, no direito nem no console vai. Vou adicionar um exemplo.

Comment: coloquei um exemplo na pergunta.

Comment: remover a classe que foi adicionada no body, clicando no body.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Veja se era isso :D

Comment: Perfeito.! Thx..

Comment: Acho que pode juntar os dois eventos pra não repetir, perai que vou editar